# Same directive different navbar styling

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to reuse the same directive for the navbar, but in the home page has a different styling than the rest of the application. What I did was, creating a `$location.path()` condition based logic to present a different navbar, like such:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('navbar',['$location', 
  function($location){
    var template = '';
    if($location.path() === '/') {
      template = 'app/templates/mainpage-navbar'
    } else {
      template = 'app/templates/navbar'
    }
    return {
      templateUrl: template
    }
  }
]);
```

My problem is, say I'm in the mainpage and then I click to go to somewhere else in the application, it won't update the new navbar, only if I do a refresh of the page.

What is the best approach here? Refresh the directive?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you wrote your code inside directive compile phase which is getting executing only once when angular directive start compiling of that DOM element. Inside your directive you should have watcher on `$location` by have `$on` on `$locationChangeSuccess` so that the function will get fire when location changes occur, and you need to execute you inside that function.

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('navbar',['$location', 
  function($location){

    //compile phase
    //this is getting executed only once.

    return {
      templateUrl: template
    }
  }
]);
```

Above code would get changed to below

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('navbar', ['$location',
  function($location) {
    return {
      template: '<div ng-include="template"></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var getTemplateUrl = function() {
          if ($location.path() === '/') {
            scope.template = 'mainpage-navbar.html';
          } else {
            scope.template = 'navbar.html';
          }
        };
        scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
          getTemplateUrl();
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KCzwWlea7vY7CqFyH1LK?p=preview)

Comment: It's not rendering the navbar, and in the chrome's console doesn't show any error

Comment: but of course :) http://plnkr.co/edit/kGvtuDQFwuYlcSIb7Ima?p=preview check if I'm missing something

Comment: @tvieira take look at edit..basically you were missing to add `angular.js` reference and made some small changes